# StarterSTS as a backup authentication store

Tags: single-sign-on, wif, adfs2.0, adfs, adlds

I have setup startersts as the ClaimsProviderTrust in ADFS 2.0. Configured the login form to be displayed by changing the ADFS 2.0 web.config entry. I am trying to customize the login process here such that when some one enter's email address he will be logging into StarterSts otherwise through Active Directory which is provided by the ADFS 2.0 Installation. I had tried the code in the post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2010/01/27/customizing-the-ad-fs-2-0-sign-in-web-pages.aspx

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    try
    {
        SignInWithTokenFromOtherSTS( UsernameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text );
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        //
        // Fall back to signing in locally with the given username and password.
        //
        SignIn( UsernameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text );
    }
}
```

I just don't know what is the values for variables `OtherSTSAddress` and `YourSTSAddress`. Is there any more configuration i need to do after making this address correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the link you provided:

```
const string OtherSTSAddress = "https://ipsts.federatedidentity.net/SecurityTokenService/InteropSts.svc/Sts";

const string YourSTSAddress = "https://your-sts/adfs/ls/";
```

So the former is the WS-Trust endpoint of StarterSTS.

The latter is the ADFS WS-Fed endpoint. Just substitute the URL of the box where you installed ADFS in the "your-sts" section.

According to the article, that's all you need.

Comment: I think the StarterSTS does not have a file named `InteropSts.svc` or neither does IdentityServerv1 or V2

Comment: Probably - you need to find the equivalent and use that. StarterSTS must have a list of endpoints somewhere.